# Angular 11 Web API Controller POST method

Tags: angular, typescript, http, post, controller

I need to create and/or reuse an object for my web API controller class to post these 4 variables too:

```
int Date, int TemperatureC, int TemperatureF, string Summary
```

I'm using the default weather forecast controller provided with the Angular template I'm using. How might I go about creating the POST method using the information I have so far?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PROBLEM.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {

        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public (int Date, int TemperatureC, int TemperatureF, string Summary) Posted { get; private set; }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post()
        {
            
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define an entity class for sending data.`Weather`  given below.

```
public class Weather
{
    public int TemperatureC {get;set;}
    public int TemperatureF {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public string Summary {get;set}

}
```

Also, you need to recieve this data in post method from body.
Your post method will be look like below.

```
   private static List<Weather> weathers=new List<Weather>()
   {
     new Weather() 
     {TemperatureC=10,Summary="Chilli",TemperatureF=40,Date=DateTime.Now }

   }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult<List<Weather>> Post([FromBody] Weather weather)
  {
     //you recieve weather data and make your changes like adding db or list
     //you can return new added value or changes in your db  
     weathers.Add(weather);

     return weathers;
  }
```

Comment: I see that this POST's directly from the controller. I had created an interface with HTTP params in order to interact with with the API previously. Is it possible to modify this to accept data from the user or rather in my situation I created a button to POST specific data upon pressing it.

Comment: Yes, of course. If you send post request from your client with a service, you can modify or accept data. Here is an angular's example about sending data to api. Chech it out [link](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#add-a-new-hero).